# How to implement Google Tag Manager In Cordova

Tags: javascript, android, cordova, google-analytics, google-tag-manager

I read [Google Tag Manager v4 - Getting Started](https://developers.google.com/tag-manager/android/v4/#getting-started) and [Integrating Google Tag Manager and Google Analytics in a SPA](http://decompile.it/blog/2013/06/21/integrating-google-tag-manager-and-google-analytics-in-a-single-page-application/)

I am not sure how it handle at the Javascript side even I could. So I want to handle at the native side. But Google's documentation little bit confusing. I find nothing about Cordova and GTM article. Any thoughts? or a step by step guide?

Comment: Have you found some answer for this please?

Comment: I have no luck to achieve this. But i am working on a POC and if it succeeded i will share it. Anyway http://www.simoahava.com/ is have great articles about GTM

Answer (score 2):

I don't know if it's still the case or not. But you can use [cordova-plugin-tag-manager](https://github.com/kraihn/cordova-plugin-tag-manager) and if you also have angular in your project, use try it with [angulartics](https://luisfarzati.github.io/angulartics/)

good luck

Comment: Am running into issues when using the above plugin with iOS. I get warnings that the binary resource file and plist file are not found. More details in this post - http://stackoverflow.com/questions/38437505/issues-in-parsing-the-json-file-in-google-tag-manager-plugin-in-cordova. Can you pls help?